# Interop method takes ref parameter, but also works without it

Tags: c#, office-interop, ref

I am using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` to create some Word files. To do so, there is the [`Application.Documents.Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.documents.add.aspx) method, which takes four `ref` arguments.

However, I can call that method as follows without any problems:

```
string filename = "myfiletemplate.dotx";
this.Application.Documents.Add(filename);
```

When I use <kbd>F12</kbd> on that `Add` method it shows me the same signature as the documentation. When I try it myself, the compiler complains:

```
public Foo(ref int i) {
}

int i = 5;
Foo(u);
```

> Argument 1 must be passed with the 'ref' keyword.

Why does that `this.Application.Documents.Add(filename)` call work?

Comment: This was a change in C# 4.0 to improve the experience with COM Interop from C#. I can't immediately find the docs to back it up, but google will give you a load of blogs that explain the changes.

Comment: See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/samng/2009/06/16/com-interop-in-c-4-0/. It's just syntactic sugar to make COM interop easier.

Comment: @GabrielNegut I found that one as well yes. I guess that's the answer.